# How to hide paramters in url while displaying Birt report

Tags: java, url, jsf, report, birt

I am calling the report from my application in JSF  the connection parameters are captured by the application and sent to the Birt, the only problem and that parameters are visible in the address bar.

is there any way to hide them or encrypt them?

I need this because the data may come from applications with different connections.

I am using

window.open(
http://localhost:8081/birt5/run?__report=Report/Bound_Polici es_Report.rptdesign&Report_StartDate=05/20/2018&Repo rt_EndDate=05/30/2018&Report_InsuranceCompanyId=0&Re port_DomicileState=New+Mexico&Report_InsuranceCarrierId= 0&Report_BusinessType=All&__format=html&__title= Compquick
)

to load the new report.

Is there any solution to hide paramters if my requirement is that the Report 
should open in new when I click on submit button in one JSF.

I would appreciate any help you could give. Thanks :)